# How to analyze multiple correlations

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

I have 4 covariates - $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$.  Three of them ($A$, $B$, $C$) independently show strong correlation with the forth one ($D$). I can create a chart in Excel for each pair ($A$-$D$, $B$-$D$, $C$-$D$), add a trend line, and get an equation for the trend line.  In my case all of them show quadratic trends with the fourth covariate $D$.

I would like to create an equation using the three covariates ($A$,$B$,$C$) to predict the forth one ($D$).

Comment: See [tag:multiple-regression].

Answer (score 0):

As @whuber said, you need a cookie-cutter [linear regression](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) (you can add polynomial so without problem). You *can* use [excel](https://www.clemson.edu/ces/phoenix/tutorials/excel/regression.html) to accomplish it, but it is better to use a statistical package (R, STATA, SPSS etc..) each of these packages have easy tools for importing the data from excel as a `.xls` or `.csv` in a fairly straightforward format. After which you get a fairly easily interpretable output.